# Vue/Nuxt 3 - Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a function that is supposed to change words every few seconds. Everything works as expected, but I get following error every few seconds in the VSC console:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent') at
> Timeout._onTimeout (.../components/home/Hero.vue:36:28) at
> listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)

I don't understand why I get this error, because when I **console.log** `word.value`, I get the element. So I have access to it and the function is working, the words change every few seconds, as expected. I'm a bit confused and don't know how to get the problem solved. I don't get the error in the Google Chrome console, only in VSC.

```html
<span ref="word"></span>
```

```js
onMounted(() => {
  randomizeText()
  wordChanger
})

onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
  clearTimeout(wordChanger)
})

const wordChanger = setInterval(randomizeText, 4000)

const word = ref(null)
const words = reactive(['Word-1', 'Word-2'])
let i = 0

function randomizeText() {
  i = randomNum(i, words.length)
  const newWord = words[i]

  setTimeout(() => {
    word.value.textContent = newWord
  }, 200) // time to allow opacity to hit 0 before changing word
}

function randomNum(num, max) {
  let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * max)

  // ensure diff num every time
  if (num === j) {
    return randomNum(i, max)
  } else {
    return j
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `const word = ref(null)` as `refs`.  You can directly call it the constant `word` in your template. It should still work the same.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ word }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Inside the `setTimeout` function, change this `word.value.textContent = newWord` to this `word.value = newWord`.

Here is the updated codes. Tested and it works.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  randomizeText()
  wordChanger
})

onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
  clearTimeout(wordChanger)
})

const wordChanger = setInterval(randomizeText, 4000)

const word = ref('') // UPDATED
const words = reactive(['Word-1', 'Word-2'])
let i = 0

function randomizeText() {
  i = randomNum(i, words.length)
  const newWord = words[i]

  setTimeout(() => {
    word.value = newWord // UPDATED
  }, 200) // time to allow opacity to hit 0 before changing word
}

function randomNum(num, max) {
  let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * max)

  // ensure diff num every time
  if (num === j) {
    return randomNum(i, max)
  } else {
    return j
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ word }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a timing issue (element not mounted while it is being changed by the code)

You can do this without setting the textContent property dirctly, by using the `v-html` directive and just changing the referenced variable (ref)
Also, you can just start the interval in the `onMounted()` hook.

```js
import {onMounted, reactive, ref} from "vue";
import {onBeforeRouteLeave} from "vue-router";

let wordChanger;

onMounted(() => {
    randomizeText()
    wordChanger = setInterval(randomizeText, 4000);
})

onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
    clearTimeout(wordChanger)
})

let word = ref('Hoi')
const words = reactive(['Word-1', 'Word-2'])
let i = 0

function randomizeText() {
    i = randomNum(i, words.length)
    const newWord = words[i]

    setTimeout(() => {
        word.value = newWord
    }, 200) // time to allow opacity to hit 0 before changing word
}

function randomNum(num, max) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * max)

    // ensure diff num every time
    if (num === j) {
        return randomNum(i, max)
    } else {
        return j
    }
}
```

```html
<span v-html="word"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably are using the ref 'word' wrong and some other details I share below:-
note: I add comments to the lines I changed to help you understand better

```
setup() {
    

    const word = ref(null);
    const words = reactive(['Word-1', 'Word-2']);

    function randomizeText(i) {
      const p = randomNum(i, words.length);
      const newWord = words[p];

      setTimeout(() => {
        word.value = newWord;
      }, 200); // time to allow opacity to hit 0 before changing word
    }

    function randomNum(num, max) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

      // ensure diff num every time
      if (num === j) {
        // notice here as well I use num instead of i
        return randomNum(num, max);
      } else {
        return j;
      }
    }
    
    const wordChanger = setInterval(randomizeText, 4000);
    
    onMounted(() => {
      randomizeText(0); // start with 0
      // wordChanger; // no need using this here
    });

    onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
      clearTimeout(wordChanger);
    });

    return {
      word,
    };
  },
```

```html
<span>{{ word }}</span>
```

here's a demo:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-rap7bb?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue